# match target row with sed or grep

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I want to catch the row contain "**Will_Liu>**" from massive_data.txt if the **n < m** or **n==0** or **m==0**, a period of the prototype is as below.

```
cat massive_data.txt
Will_Liu> set Name.*  xxx
============================================
Id  Name     Para     status              
============================================
1  name-1    xxxxx      OK                
2  name-2    xxxxx      OK
3  name-3    xxxxx      Not_OK  
.   ...      ....       OK
.   ...      ....       OK
m  name-m    ....       Not_OK  
============================================
Total: m name attempted, n name set OK
```

In the above code, the "m" and "n" are variable, if the **n < m** or **n==0** or **m==0**, print the rows contain "**Will_Liu**>" ;
if n==m and both of them !=0, just skip and ignore this situation.

I just could use "grep" and "sed" to grasp key points like those:

```
cat test.txt
Will_Liu> set Name_group1   xxx
============================================
Id  Name     Para     status              
============================================
1  name-1    xxxxx      OK                
2  name-2    xxxxx      OK
3  name-3    xxxxx      Not_OK  
============================================
Total: 3 name attempted, 2 name set OK

Will_Liu> set Name_group2   yyy
============================================
Id  Name     Para     status              
============================================
1  name-4    xxxxx      OK                
2  name-5    xxxxx      Not_OK
3  name-6    xxxxx      Not_OK  
============================================
Total: 3 name attempted, 1 name set OK
```

I could use "sed" and "grep" command like this:

```
sed -n "/Total: 3 name attempted,/p" test.txt
Total: 3 name attempted, 2 name set OK
Total: 3 name attempted, 1 name set OK

grep -B 9 "Total: 3 name attempted" test.txt | sed -n '/Will_Liu>/p'
Will_Liu> set Name_group1   xxx
Will_Liu> set Name_group2   yyy
```

in the grep command the 9 is 3+**6**, the **6** is base on the format of the structure, it's a fixed value.

So how can I introduce 2 variates to define the "**m**" and "**n**" and improve my code to get expected result from massive_data.txt? 
My expect output:

```
Will_Liu> set Name1   xxx
Will_Liu> set Name2   yyy
Will_Liu> set Name3   zzz
 .            .        .
 .            .        .
 .            .        .
```

Comment: Please work on clarifying this question.  There are many undefined terms: for example: "target row" or "settled row" or "behind code" or "the variate."  If you want good answers, your writing needs to be clear and precise.  Don't leave us guessing.

Comment: So sorry for the inconvenience, the "target row" means "Will_Liu> set Name.*   xxx", and the "behind code" means "above", I will reedit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, any previous line you want to print matches another pattern. In these cases it is better to store the last candidate to be printed and when you reach your condition, decide what to do with it. For example

```
awk '/^Will_Liu/{
        last_will=$0
    }

    /^Total/{
        m=$2; n=$5
        if (m>n || (m==0 && n==0))
            print last_will

    }' file
```

In cases where you really don't have any pattern to select the last candidate to print, and you have to decide some line number to print after a math operation on matched line data, then you could double pass a file, or use `tac` to invert the input or keep all last lines in a hash array or any similar approach. These approaches could be not efficient sometimes. For example, with storing all lines, which is not recommended for your case

```
awk '{ line[NR]=$0 }

    /^Total/{
        m=$2; n=$5
        if (m>n || (m==0 && n==0))
            print line[NR-(m+5)]

    }' file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,sir.
My co-worker provided me a new idea to fix the problem. We can switch a direction to select target part.
    grep "Will_Liu> \| name attempted, " massive_data.txt | awk '{a[NR]=$0; if($1 == "Total:" && $2>$5 || $2==0){print a[NR-1]}}'
In this code, we can filter the row contain "Will_Liu" or "name attempted", then to judge and select the row within "Will_Liu"